# Python Class Object Sharing between child processes

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I create a Python class which objects can be shareable between parent and child processes (child can manipulate the object).

My code have `'eventlet.monkey_patch()'` and my child processes are created using `'multiprocessing.Process()'` module.

I tried to create it with using `'multiprocessing.managers BaseManager()` and `'NamespaceProxy()'` but due to `'monkey_patch()'` it is giving Error :

```
'Resource Temporarily Unavailable'.
```

Can some one give me other possible solutions to crate such a class with example. I am using Python 2.7.6 and OS is Ubuntu 14.04